Highest Attenuation with Unit Resistors?
What is the most efficient unit resistor arrangement for high ratio attenuation ?
For example, if I want to attenuate a (voltage) signal by a large factor (e.g. approximately 1000x), I could use 999 R in series and 1 at the bottom for a 1/1000 attenuation. That would use a total of 1000 resistors. Alternatively, I could use 31 resistors in series joining 31 resistors in parallel for an attenuation of 1/962, using only 62 resistors.
I could build a R-2R DAC (uses 3 unit resistors per bit) with 8 bits, using about 32 total resistors and getting attenuation of 1/1024.
Is there a theoretically better arrangement for similar attenuation levels ?

What a strange but intriguing question. May I ask why you're curious?

It came up in a discussion with some colleagues about how resistor networks work.

This is 'better' than R-2R -- use that topology, but just use single resistors in place of the 2R. Now (in the limit), the attenuation is approx 0.382/stage (½*(3-sqrt(5)), so 7 stages gets /1000, and uses 14 resistors (there are some approximations there).
